# Преобразование unix метки в процентное соотношение

Tags: javascript, html

Не могу решить задачку.

Есть функция `time()` и переменная `$time`.

К примеру `unix` метка на данный момент вот такое число 1608157239 а в переменной `$time` это же число только +3600.

Получается что переменная `$time` == 1608160839.

Потом я меняю значение переменной отнимая текущую unix метку:

```
$time = $time - time();
```

На выходе получаю динамическое число которое каждую секунду меньше на единицу и через 3600 секунд достигнет значение 0.

Так же есть HTML разметка:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 50%">
        <span class="sr-only">50% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Задача:

Как вы видите в html разметки есть атрибут style и ширина в нем статическая.

Как преобразовать полученную динамическую переменную в проценты и подставить в верстку?

То есть на момент создание переменной которая равна 3600 в верстке должно быть значение `width: 0%`, а когда переменная `$time` достигнет 0 `width` должно равняться 100%.

Прошу помощи в реализации!

Comment: Вам надо передать переменную в js и динамически менять значение

Comment: Как выше написали, эта задача рещается на яваскрипте

Comment: [1](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp) [2](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp)

Answer (score 4):

Если период всегда `3600 секунд`, то я не вижу смысла передавать переменную. В данном случае я использую `анимацию CSS` для изменения ширины (и `36 секунд`), думаю что это оптимально и плавно. Что касается значений процентов то устанавливаю их через интервал и соответвенно видны рывки, но это можно поправить поиграв со значением интревала и инкрементом счетчика. Кнопки добавил исключительно для демонстрации - достаточно вызова соответсвующих функций.

```js
const MAX_TIME = 36;
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('#reset');
const runBtn = document.querySelector('#run');
const progress = document.querySelector('.progress');
const sr = document.querySelector('.sr-only');
let intervalId = null;

progress.onanimationend = onAnimationEnd;
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', onReset, false);
runBtn.addEventListener('click', onRun, false);

resetBtn.disabled = true;

function onAnimationEnd () {
  progress.classList.add('filled');
  progress.classList.remove('runned');
  runBtn.disabled = false; 
}

function finish(){
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    runBtn.disabled = false; 
    resetBtn.disabled = true;
    intervalId = null;
}

function onReset () {
  if (intervalId) {
    finish();
  }
  progress.classList.remove('runned');
  progress.classList.remove('filled');
  progress.classList.add('reseted');
  sr.textContent = `0%`
}

function onRun () {
  if (intervalId) return;
  runBtn.disabled = true; 
  resetBtn.disabled = false;

  let val = 0; 
  intervalId = setInterval(() => { 
    val += 1;
    if (val === MAX_TIME) finish()
    sr.textContent = `${Math.ceil(val * 100 / MAX_TIME )}%`
  } ,1000)

  progress.classList.remove('filled');
  progress.classList.add('runned');
}
```

```css
.progress {
  z-index: 100;
  background: red;
  width: 0%;
}

.reseted {
  width: 0%;
}

.filled {
  width: 100%;
}

.runned {
  animation: 36s run linear;
}

@keyframes run {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar">
          <span class="sr-only">0%</span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  <button id="run">Run</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Число 3600 секунд это пример для ровного понимания.

Comment: @verstala возможно я не понял задачу из ее описания, нужны подробности, потому что я тоже удивился такой точности, но судя по тому что проголосовало за 4 человека они поняли все точно так же как и я

Comment: @verstala если что буду рад дополнить свой ответ под конкретный кейс

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понял вас, какая-то операция работает на стороне сервера, она длится один час и вам нужно на клиент отдавать прогресс выполнения операции.

Так же, мне кажется, что сервер у вас на php (исправьте если ошибаюсь).

---

Начнем с простой математики.
Если 0 соответствует 0%, а 3600 - 100%, можно посчитать, что

```
percent = n / (max - min) * 100
```

Таким образом `min` - время начала операции, `max` - время окончания операции (время начала + 1 час), `n` - время, прошедшее со времени начала.

---

```js
// Важно заметить, что в js таймстамп содержит милисекунды, то есть число в 1000 раз больше
// const beginTimestamp = <?php echo $date * 1000; ?>;
const beginTimestamp = Date.now();
// Если изменить это число - прогрессбар будет двигатся быстрее/медленнее
const duration = 3600 * 1000;
const endTimestamp = beginTimestamp + duration;

const getPercentProgress = () => {
  const now = Date.now();
  const percent = (now - beginTimestamp) / (endTimestamp - beginTimestamp) * 100;
  return Math.min(100, Math.max(0, percent)); // чтоб прогресс был в пределах 0..100
};

const progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");
const textLabel = document.querySelector(".sr-only");

setInterval(() => {
  const progress = getPercentProgress();

  progressBar.style.width = progress + "%";
  textLabel.innerText = progress.toFixed(2) + "% Complete"; // 2 знака после точки
}, 100);
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  display: block;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #da411d;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 50%">
    <span class="sr-only">0% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```